# WSO2 ESB Analytics Clustering

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-esb

Is it possible to cluster ESB Analytics? because I heard that ESB Analytics is built over WSO2 DAS. If possible could anyone please point me in the right direction? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thunku, according to WSO2 documentation you can.
Documentation says:

> You may need more than one WSO2 ESB Analytics server in a clustered deployment depending on the load of requests handled by the ESB cluster. The possible deployment patterns for WSO2 ESB Analytics is the same as that for WSO2 Data Analytics Server.....

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Prerequisites+to+Publish+Statistics

For detailed instructions visit:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Minimum+High+Availability+Deployment+for+WSO2+DAS+3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can cluster ESB Analytics. This is built over WSO2 DAS. You can find the WSO2EI Analytics clustering docs - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Clustering+the+Analytics+Profile.